# jquery hover function fast mouse in partial fire

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery hover function, there are two animations and three .css functions.  When you rollover quickly there is mixture of strange firing.  I have it set up using a jsbin, you can see when you roll over and then away it prompts the hover, when you do it at a normal rate it works correctly, when you do it fast you can see the mistakes.  I need help figuring this out, any suggestions I can get would be very very helpful, thanks in advance.

http://jsbin.com/isigoz/67/edit

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the jQuery.finish() function so that you don't end up with a long queue of animations after fast mouse movement. So change the following lines to include the .finish() function before the animation:

```
$('.backing').finish().fadeOut();

$('#'+gymlocation+'_back').finish().fadeIn();

$('.backing').finish().fadeOut();

$('#'+current_back).finish().fadeIn();
```

You then have the issue of your mouseover/out areas are restricted to the text & not the whole coloured area - which is kind of weird but might be what you want? So I haven't suggested a solution for that.

You also have duplicate javascript functionality which might lead to unwanted animations. Remove the second to last section of code:

```
$('#menu-wrapper').mouseleave(function() { ... and everything in-between ... });
```

because you already have this animation with the call to `hover()` here:

```
$('#menu-wrapper').hover( handlerIn, handlerOut );
```

with the second argument `handlerOut`.

It seems to be much better now - not sure if that is what you are expecting.

**Edit**

Firstly, you should not add the finish function to all animations. Please see my answer. You have added it to the mini-menu animations which you shouldn't.

Your problem is with this line:

```
$('#menu-text, .backing').css({
  display:'none'
});
```

change it to this:

```
$('#menu-text, .backing').fadeOut();
```

Why is because you have other animations that affect the display property of the text-menu which then makes it visible after you have hidden it. The fadOut() lasts longer than the mouse hover. So with this it seems to be working well.

Here is the link: http://jsbin.com/isigoz/87/

Comment: hmmm, so this didn't seem to fix it for me.  There was a duplicate function, that was wrong, so I deleted that.  But it's not the rolling over of the text, it's the whole menu and it's the collapse and uncollapse animating effect that's the issue.  When you roll over and back out really really fast the text shows up but then doesn't go away again like it should on roll out, and the yellow ring doesn't fade back in when it gets smaller.  So you're left with a small white menu with text showing.  There should be no text and a yellow ring http://jsbin.com/isigoz/81/edit updated here.